# UICollectionView, Images inside a cell does not load until the cell is scrolled off screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Using Xcode 6 beta 6, I have used a standard View Controller and placed a Collection view into it. Following this, I have added a prototype cell from which an array on the CollectionViewController.m file provides the images.

While the images do appear, they do not load until after that cell has been scrolled off the screen and then back on. This is stopping any images from loading when the app opens until the user scrolls down.

The images are stored locally in the file, not a Database.

Despite the lack of images, I have linked the cells to another view controller, and even though no image is displayed, the segue still operates.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are setting the `UIImage` on the cell image view out of the main thread. Wrap the setter code into a following snippet:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

    cell.imageView.image = {UIImage object you've got};

}];
```

Optionally you could also try different, single-line replacement approach, if possible:

```
[cell.imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:{UIImage object} waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I can't find what kind of cell you mean in fact; in every case, apply the same on a particular target image view, no matter if it's a part of your cell as a property or not.

Comment: I am talking about the UICollectionViewCell provided in a collection view.

Comment: Yeah, I should guess so. In that case, unlike in `UITableViewCell`, `UIImageView` is not a direct part (property) of cell (unless added by yourself), but probably manually added as a subview. But nothing changes, you just apply the code above directly on the `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use willDisplayCell method to assign image.
first initial image then create cell.

here is the code :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;}



-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
imageView.image = images[indexPath.row];}
```

And don't forget to reload collection view after your data is ready to be loaded:

```
[_myCollection reloadData];
```